# TextMate can't autocomplete jquery methods by pressing esc?

Tags: macos, autocomplete, textmate, jquery

I'm using TextMate (mac), I was told that this app can autocomplete jQuery methods or functions by pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.

I have the script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("div")...
});
</script>
```

When I tried to finish `$("div").` with something (for example `toggleClass`), when I type `$("div").to` then press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key. Nothing shows up!

Do I have to install some kind of plugin in order to make it work, or is there any other editor app that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to the question is yes.

textmate autocomplete can only ac from the words within the document or methods predefined to the language you are working on. say in php, when you type in_ and press esc, you start to see the native php methods.

https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-tmbundle this is a popular jquery bundle for textmate, it does not work the way to want but it's useful.